# Webkit css box issue

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a css3 boxflex layout in webkit, but for some reason, `#main` (the purple one) isn't filling 100% of the screen like the css is telling it to: http://jsfiddle.net/qxxZv/
How do I get it to fill the whole height available? This is just a basic layout with header, middle area with sidebar/content, and a footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, you need your html and body tag to have a height of 100%:

```
html,body {margin:0;padding:0; height: 100%;}
```

jsFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jackrugile/63bg2/

Comment: Hmm, it makes `#main` fill the whole height, but it has `-webkit-box-orient` set to `vertical`, so shouldn't the boxes inside of it be expanding? I've never used flexbox layouts before

Comment: Heh, just figured it out - I forgot to set `-webkit-box-flex` to `1` on `.screen` thanks @jackrugile!

Comment: @robert_nachos Awesome, glad that worked! I knew the html and body had to have 100% height, but I am not familiar with boxflex. Glad that fixed it. I need to check out boxflex for sure.